# Juntar colunas no histograma ggplot

Tags: r, data, histograma

Tenho esses dados https://pastebin.com/9tBv1Enm e tentei fazer um histograma com x= data e y= contagem

```
ggplot(ind_geral1, aes(x=mes_ano))+
   geom_histogram(binwidth=40) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3)) +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y")
```

Acontece que apenas o texto do eixo x ficam de 6 em 6 meses. Como faço para que as barras se agrupem de 6 em 6 meses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui vão duas maneiras de fazer o que a pergunta pede. O problema está em agrupar as datas por semestre. O R tem a classe `"Date"` mas não há uma classe `"Semester"` portanto é preciso fazer manualmente. O pacote `zoo` tem só classes para

- Ano e mês, `"yearmon"`;
- Ano e trimestre, `"yearqtr"`.

Mas não tem uma classe para ano e semestre.
As duas seguintes instruções são comuns aos dois modos de traçar o gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)
ind_geral1$mes_ano <- as.Date(ind_geral1$mes_ano)
```

## Ano e semestre em R base

Define-se uma função `cut_fun` para dividir as datas em semestres. Essa função só utiliza funções R base para datas.

```
cut_fun <- function(x){
  mn <- format(min(x), "%Y")
  mx <- format(max(x), "%Y")
  mn <- as.Date(paste0(mn, "-01-01"))
  mx <- as.Date(paste0(mx, "-12-31"))
  s <- seq.Date(mn, mx, by = "6 months")
  as.Date(cut.Date(x, s))
}

ggplot(ind_geral1, aes(x = cut_fun(mes_ano))) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  labs(x = "Semestre", y = "Contagens")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Pacote `dplyr`.

Esta segunda maneira utiliza os pacotes `dplyr` e `lubridate`. Cria-se uma variável de classe `"factor"` a partir das datas. Mas antes do *pipe* tem que se definir os níveis do fator.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

rng <- year(range(ind_geral1$mes_ano))
rng <- ymd(paste(rng, c(1, 12), c(1, 31)))
levs <- seq(rng[1], rng[2], by = "6 months")
levs <- as.character(zoo::as.yearmon(levs))

ind_geral1 %>%
  mutate(ano_semestre = (month(mes_ano) > 6) + 1L,
         ano_semestre = c(1, 7)[ano_semestre],
         ano_semestre = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(year(mes_ano), ano_semestre, "01", sep = "-")),
         ano_semestre = factor(ano_semestre, levels = levs)) %>% 
  count(ano_semestre, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ano_semestre, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3)) +
  labs(x = "Semestre", y = "Contagens")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]